# Regex ignore double chars

Tags: regex

I try to parse a language string with this format:

```
ll_LL@anytext;ll_LL@anytext;ll_LL@anytext;
```

To extraxt each of the languages i use this regex:

```
[a-z]+[_][A-Z]+[@].+?(?=;)
// result: [ll_LL@anytext, ll_LL@anytext, ll_LL@anytext]
```

The issue i have is,that 1-N double semicolon can appear inside the text and should be escaped. Like this:

```
ll_LL@any;;text;ll_LL@anyt;;ex;;t;
// should result to [l_LL@any;;text , ll_LL@anyt;;ex;;t]
```

I got stuck with this two approaches:

```
[a-z]+[_][A-Z]+[@](.+?[;;]+?|.+?)(?=;)

[a-z]+[_][A-Z]+[@].+?(?=;{1})
```

Is there any way to prevent the positive lookahead to stop on double smicolons between `[@]` and `(?=;)` ?

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: `(?<!;);(?!;)` in PHP if you use `preg_split()` https://regex101.com/r/IHSBY1/1/

Comment: `var_dump( preg_split( '/(?<!;);(?!;)/', trim( 'll_LL@any;;text;ll_LL@anyt;;ex;;t;ll_LL@anytext;ll_LL@anytext;ll_LL@anytext;', ';' ) ) );`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus just only regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```cs
[a-z]+_[A-Z]+@[^;]*(?:;;[^;]*)*(?=;)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zHgykd/1). Note you may omit `(?=;)` if it is not necessary to check for the char presence, `[a-z]+_[A-Z]+@[^;]*(?:;;[^;]*)*` [will yield](https://regex101.com/r/zHgykd/2) the same results.

**Details**

- `[a-z]+` - one or more lowercase ASCII letters
- `_` - a `_` char
- `[A-Z]+` - one or more uppercase ASCII letters
- `@` - a `@` char
- `[^;]*` - zero or more chars other than `;`
- `(?:;;[^;]*)*` - zero or more occurrences of `;;` and then any zero or more chars other than `;`
- `(?=;)` - a positive lookahead that requires a `;` to appear immediately to the right of the current location.
- `[a-z]+_[A-Z]+@[^;]*(?:;;[^;]*)*(?=;)`

Comment: Thank you Wiktor. This solves my issue. Also appreciate your further explanation.